# inserting audio in radio button html

Tags: javascript, html, audio

This is the code for playing an audio when a radio button is clicked and evaluated by a Submit button. 
There are two sound files separately for two radio buttons respectively. These files are not playing when they are evaluated by a Submit button. Please check out that whether the code works properly or not.

```
    <html>
    <head>

    <script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

        var snd = new Audio('\Users\raja\Desktop\abs.mp3');

        var x = new Audio('\Users\raja\Desktop\new.mp3');

function ValidateForm(form){
ErrorText= "";
if ( ( form.gender[0].checked == false ) && ( form.gender[1].checked == false ) ) 
{
alert ( "Please choose your Gender: Male or Female" ); 
return false; 
}

if ( ( form.gender[0].checked == true ) && ( form.gender[1].checked == false ) ) 
{

        snd.play();    

        alert ( "Your Gender:Male"); 

return false; 
}

if ( ( form.gender[0].checked == false ) && ( form.gender[1].checked == true ) ) 
{
    x.play(); 


    alert ( "Your Gender:Female");
    return false; 
}


if (ErrorText= "") { form.submit() }
}

</script>


</head>

<body>
<form name="feedback" action="#" method=post>
Your Gender: 
<p><input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male"> Male </p>

<p><input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" > Female</p>

<input type="button" name="SubmitButton" value="Submit" onClick="ValidateForm(this.form)">

<input type="reset" value="Reset">

</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code works properly for me and check weather the file is loaded using webinspector.

Comment: I don't have any idea about the WebInspector. Please tell me about it

Comment: Right click on your webpage and go to the "inspect element".A new window will open at the bottom of your screen now click on the console and check weather there are any errors in it.

Comment: No errors are there in the file